# linear image stitching using emgu.cv in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, emgucv

I have a device that rotates an object and takes a picture of a portion of the object at regular intervals.  Currently, I have 30 pictures.  To stitch the images into a flat image, I am taking a slice right out of the center of each picture of a fixed width (between 50 and 75 pixels).  I am trying to stitch these slices together into a flat image of the original picture using the EMGU CV Stitching library with the sample stitching code that comes with EMGU.  I am testing with between 5 and 10 slices at a time.  Sometimes, I am getting an error that says "Error, need more images".  When I do get a result, it looks terrible with weird curvatures.  I don't need any spatial adjustments.  I just want to stitch them in a linear fashion from left to right.  Any ideas, either using EMGU or other?

Here are a few slices and the result:

[image: Slice 1]  [image: Slice 2]  [image: Slice 3]  [image: Slice 4]  [image: Result]

Why is the resulting image not the same height as the 4 slices?  What must be done just to stitch these together in a linear fashion so that the text is continuous?

Here is the code I am using:

```
  private void selectImagesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.CheckFileExists = true;
            dlg.Multiselect = true;

            if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                sourceImageDataGridView.Rows.Clear();

                Image<Bgr, byte>[] sourceImages = new Image<Bgr, byte>[dlg.FileNames.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < sourceImages.Length; i++)
                {
                    sourceImages[i] = new Image<Bgr, byte>(dlg.FileNames[i]);

                    using (Image<Bgr, byte> thumbnail = sourceImages[i].Resize(200, 200, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.Inter.Cubic, true))
                    {
                        DataGridViewRow row = sourceImageDataGridView.Rows[sourceImageDataGridView.Rows.Add()];
                        row.Cells["FileNameColumn"].Value = dlg.FileNames[i];
                        row.Cells["ThumbnailColumn"].Value = thumbnail.ToBitmap();
                        row.Height = 200;
                    }
                }
                try
                {
                    //only use GPU if you have build the native binary from code and enabled "NON_FREE"
                    using (Stitcher stitcher = new Stitcher(false))
                    {

                        using (AKAZEFeaturesFinder finder = new AKAZEFeaturesFinder())
                        {

                            stitcher.SetFeaturesFinder(finder);
                            using (VectorOfMat vm = new VectorOfMat())
                            {
                                Mat result = new Mat();
                                vm.Push(sourceImages);

                                Stopwatch watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                                this.Text = "Stitching";
                                Stitcher.Status stitchStatus = stitcher.Stitch(vm, result);
                                watch.Stop();

                                if (stitchStatus == Stitcher.Status.Ok)
                                {
                                    resultImageBox.Image = result;
                                    this.Text = String.Format("Stitched in {0} milliseconds.", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show(this, String.Format("Stiching Error: {0}", stitchStatus));
                                    resultImageBox.Image = null;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                finally
                {
                    foreach (Image<Bgr, Byte> img in sourceImages)
                    {
                        img.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your sample input/output ?

Comment: Not sure why you are using a feature-finder as [this link](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Image_Stitching_in_CSharp) shows `Stitcher` is able to do its job without any feature-finder.

Comment: Removing the feature-finder actually greatly improved the result, at least with the 4 slices added to the question.  I am going to see what happens when I use more and more slices.

Comment: What causes the "Need More Images" error ?

Comment: [Stitching module's strange behavior](http://answers.opencv.org/question/2773/stitching-modules-strange-behavior-part-i/)